# How to add audio URLs to carplay CPNowPlaying Template to play the audio and it controls

Tags: xcode, carplay

```
 // Set the handler for image-specific actions
                item.listImageRowHandler = { _, imageIndex, completion in
                    print("Tapped image at index \(imageIndex) for category: \(category)")
                    self.setPlayer()
                    self.interfaceController?.pushTemplate(CPNowPlayingTemplate.shared, animated: true)
                    completion()
                }
```

```
  func setPlayerNowPlayingInformation() {
          var nowPlayingInfo: [String: Any] = [:]
                    
          nowPlayingInfo = [MPMediaItemPropertyTitle: "Media Title"]
                    
          if let image = UIImage (named: "Card create tutorial-0") {
             nowPlayingInfo[MPMediaItemPropertyArtwork] = MPMediaItemArtwork(boundsSize: image.size, requestHandler: { size -> UIImage in
                 return image
              })
          }
          MPNowPlayingInfoCenter.default().nowPlayingInfo = nowPlayingInfo
    }
    
    func setPlayer() {
          let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/BabyElephantWalk60.wav")!)
          player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
          player.rate = 1.0
          player.play()
          self.setPlayerNowPlayingInformation()
      }
```

I found some snippets setting Audio player and playing the content by the provided code I can able to listen the audio but not able to sync with cpnowplaying template how can i sync with it and how can i get control over the audios

Comment: are you registering for remote events?

Comment: Seems not registering, can i have any source if you have any ?